# Move an Azure VM to a VNET

Tags: azure

Is it possible to move an already created VM in Azure (different affinity group) to an existing VNET?

Are there commands under the hood to do this (powershell, cmdlets)?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently you can't join VMs to a virtula network after they are created, you must do this during VM creation time as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazureconnectivity/thread/b8486c3f-a969-4fb3-a95c-db80e76e407f)

What you could do is delete your Virtual Machine which will delete the VM configuration but your OS disk will still be saved at Azure Storage. After that you can create a new Virtual Machine using the saved OS disk and during the VM configuration time, you can add it to your virtual network.

Comment: Awesome, I had a feeling that would be the workaround,, thanks Avkash!